# Enzyme - Testing onClick of child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I very new to testing and I am currently testing React components with jest/enzyme.
I have a parent component

**ParentComp.jsx**

```
export class ParentComp extends React.Component {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedTemplate: "",
      disabled: true
    };

    return <Modal
      header={<h2>Header</h2>}
      visible={true}
      footer={<span>
        <Button
          disabled={false}
          onClick={ () => {
            sessionStorage.setItem('id', this.state.id);
          }}
        >
          Continue
        </Button>
     }>
         <h1> My modal </h1>
     </Modal>
}
```

How would I go about testing the onClick and making sure the sessionStorage is tested?
I've already tried:

**ParentComp.spec.jsx**

```
    const wrapper = shallow(<ParentComp/>);
    wrapper.find(Modal).first().props().footer.find(Button).simulate('click')
    jest.spyOn(window.localStorage.__proto__, 'setItem');
    window.localStorage.__proto__.setItem = jest.fn();

    // assertions as usual:
    expect(localStorage.setItem).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(global.sessionStorage.getItem).toBecalledWith('id',1)
}
```

I thankfully don't get any actual errors, however, my sessionStorage line in ParentComp is apparently not being covered. How would I go about covering this line?

Comment: can you post the output of `console.log(wrapper.debug())` on the line before the error?

Comment: @Shadab added that line of code and it doesn;t actually do anything. Is the output supposed to show on terminal? Sorry, as I said I'm new at testing

Comment: What is at really your footer? Button only or `<span><Button /><span>`?

Comment: @tmhao2005 it's ```<span><Button /><span>```

Comment: I dropped you a hint :)

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea to call directly prop `onClick` directly in this case instead of simulating of click. As long as you can find your `<Button />` in your footer then call its prop of `onClick`. Let's try:

```js
// You can console.log to see what is the correct to select the right one
// I'm not sure below route is correct :) 
const yourButton = wrapper.find(Modal).first().props().footer.props.children;

yourButton.props.onClick();
```